# Test for end of line and white space

Tags: c++, file-io

I am reading a file of 5 doubles in a line through a for loop and storing them into a vector of structs and sometimes there is less then 5 doubles on the line. The file looks something like

111.111 222.222 333.333 444.444 555.555

666.666

777.777 (whitespace) 888.888 999.999

```
struct temp_struct{
    double d1,d2,d3,d4,d5
};
vector<temp_struct> data;
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    File>>data.at(i).d1>>data.at(i).d2>>data.at(i).d3>>data.at(i).d4>>data.at(i).d5;
```

Is there a way to test for the empty space after 666.666 and inbetween 777.777 and 888.888.

Because right now the way I am reading it in, after 666.666 it will go to the next line of the file and read 777.777 and 888.888 999.999 so that the struct looks like
data.at(1).d1=666.666 data.at(1).d2=777.777 data.at(1).d3=888.888 and data.at(1).d4=999.999 where I would rather have

```
data.at(1).d1=666.666, break because of end of line 
data.at(2).d1=777.777, data.at(2).d2=0, data.at(3).d3=888.8888
```

I am programming in VS2010 C++

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to parse line-based text is to use `std::getline()` in combination with an `std::istringstream`, e.g.:

```
for (std::string line; std::getline(in, line); ) {
    std::istringstream lin(line);
    // parse the line using `line`
}
```

There are other approaches, too, though. For example, it is possible to set up a stream to not consider a newline whitespace: this way, trying to read numbers when a newline is encountered the attempt to read the value would fail! The way to change what is considered whitespace is to install a custom `std::locale` object with a custom version of `std::ctype<char>`.